# What is the best way to remove elements in a std:list<User_Define> that satisfy certain conditions?

Tags: c++, list, vector, stdlist, remove-if

I have a user-defined structure like this:

```
struct Cell{
   int dirty;
   double data;
   Cell* c;
 //  bool operator==(const struct Cell& other) {
 //   /* I am not sure if I need this function here...*/
 //  }
};
```

Then, I defined a list like this:

```
list<Cell> cell_list;
```

What I want to do is to delete any elements in "cell_list" that satisfy the condition

```
(certain_cell.dirty == 1)
```

Could anybody give me some instructions on how to effectively realize the above operations?

Comment: Use `remove_if`. Something like `cell_list.remove_if( [](Cell& c){return c.dirty;} );` And `dirty` should presumably be a `bool`.

Comment: @ooga Answers belong as answers.

Comment: @Barry It's such a trivial question that I thought I'd give the OP a chance to delete it.

Comment: @ooga Thank you for your reply. I am a C++ beginner so sorry about my silly question.  I tried your method, but got " warning: lambda expressions only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 " and " error: no matching function for call to 'std::list<Cell>::remove_if(MyClass::myfunction(int*, int)::__lambda0)'
         cell_list.remove_if([](const Cell& c) {return (c.dirty == 1);});
"

Comment: @ooga Because I will probably add my codes to some bigger codes of others which won't use c++11 for compiling. How can I get around this error?

Comment: It's not a silly question. I just thought it might not be that useful to others. But I could be wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it without lambdas (i.e., pre-C++11) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

struct Cell {
    bool dirty;
    Cell(bool dirt=false) : dirty(dirt) { }
};

typedef std::list<Cell> CellList;

bool isDirty(const Cell& c) {
    return c.dirty;
}

int main() {
    CellList cells;
    cells.push_back(Cell());
    cells.push_back(Cell());
    cells.push_back(Cell(true));
    cells.push_back(Cell());
    cells.push_back(Cell(true));

    for (CellList::const_iterator i=cells.begin(); i!=cells.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << i->dirty << '\n';
    std::cout << '\n';

    cells.remove_if( isDirty );

    for (CellList::const_iterator i=cells.begin(); i!=cells.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << i->dirty << '\n';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Can I suggest `remove_if( &isDirty );` for readability instead. Just `isDirty` looks like you forgot to call the function.

Answer (score 2):

`list` actually has a member function named [`remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove):

```
cell_list.remove_if([](const Cell& cell){
    return cell.dirty == 1;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, sir! But when I compile it. I got errors like this: " warning: lambda expressions only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 " and " error: no matching function for call to 'std::list<Cell>::remove_if(MyClass::myfunction(int*, int)::__lambda0)' cell_list.remove_if([](const Cell& c) {return (c.dirty == 1);}); " I know that maybe I compile it with "-std=c++11" can solve this, but is there any other way to get around this compile error? (I don't want to use c++11 because I will  integrate my codes to someone else 's codes which are not compiled with c++11 )

Comment: There are very little reason to stay compatible with C++03. Not only is it 12 years old, its also the previous-previous standard. There are not many compatibility issues with C++11, upgrading is usually a breeze.

Answer (score 0):

This can be used for all containers, but may be quite inefficient
on continuous containers such as `vector`. This can especially come
in handy if you want to process all, and remove some elements of
a list in one pass.

```
list<Cell> cells;
list<Cell>::iterator itr = cells.begin();
while( itr != cells.end() )
{
    if( itr->dirty == 1 )
        itr = cells.erase(itr);
    else
        ++itr;
}
```

Comment: There are algorithms to do this better. Writing a raw loop like this is inefficient and error-prone.